# How to set the frame's background using class ttk.Style?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a tkinter interface and created a ttk.Style object to make it easy to change the design. However, when I try to change some characteristic of the frame or labelframe, I don't see changes in the widget.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

colors = [
    '#203864',
    '#ADB9CA'
]

myfont = ('calibri', 18)

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create('MyTheme', parent='alt', settings={
    'TFrame':{
        'configure':{'background':colors[0]}
    },
    'TLabel':{
        'configure':{'background':colors[0], 'font':myfont, 'foreground':colors[1]}
    }
})
style.theme_use('MyTheme')

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

tk.Label(frame, text='MyTheme').pack(padx=100, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Sorry for my English, I'm learning.

Comment: When I use your code and add just enough other code to make it work, everything works as expected and the ttk frame has the appropriate color. It would help if you could provide a complete [mcve] within the question, rather than link to a full program on another site.

Comment: @BryanOakley OK

Comment: Are you on a mac by chance? I know it has some weird behavior with tk.

Comment: @AlbertoMQ no, i'm using windows

Comment: hmm, if you set parent='default' and then do theme_use('default') does it work?

Comment: @AlbertoMQ no, i've tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The themes only work for ttk widgets, and your code is using a tk frame. You need to change your frame to this:

```
frame = ttk.Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
#       ^^^
```